# Cannot connect DSL after upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: drivers, ethernet

After upgrade Ubuntu I cannot connect to DSL. I have system message:

```
(1) *Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/9' failed in libnm-glib.*
```

What is it? I have got all the drivers from manufacture's site (Realtek 8101-1.026.00) and put it into the right directory, but I cannot install as it written in readme file. The Xterm writes that:

```
user@user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo sh /usr/src/r8101.026.00/r8101.026.00/autorun.sh
[sudo] password for user: 
sh: 0: Can't open /usr/src/r8101.026.00/r8101.026.00/autorun.sh
user@user-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:48:1c:18:0a:ba  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
lo        Link encap:Локальная петля (Loopback)  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7562 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7562 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:598663 (598.6 KB)  TX bytes:598663 (598.6 KB)
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 70:18:8b:a6:e8:b9  
          inet addr:192.168.137.71  Bcast:192.168.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::7218:8bff:fea6:e8b9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:32001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29498 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:20527596 (20.5 MB)  TX bytes:5301087 (5.3 MB)
```

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This is [Ubuntu bug 1438003](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1438003) and it has a workaround:

> I'm hitting this bug too, and so far working around it by going to Edit connections → Edit the network you want to connect to → manually input the WPA2 password in the Wi-Fi Security tab → Save, then it connects without problems.

[image: workaround screen shot]